# Install a driver for your network adapter

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking

I just installed windows 7 and am now dualbooting with ubuntu. However, when I try to connect, I am told that I need to install a driver for my network adapter.

After looking in my device manager, I found that there was no branch for my network adapter. Internet and adapter worked perfectly fine on ubuntu 16.04.

Output of lspci|grep -i net:

```
    Network controller: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 1000 [Condor Peak]
```

I'm on a Toshiba satellite p755.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I checked the model number and went on Toshiba's website. They have a menu where you pick the laptop and OS and you can  download drivers, so I downloaded the network driver onto a USB from ubuntu and installed it in windows.